# ¿Como publicar un software como software libre?

Tags: github, licencias

tengo un software que quisiera compartir al mundo, basicamente quiero que el software sea libre que otras personas pueda contribuir a mejorar al mio o 
y si se hace otro basado en el código del mio tenga que ese nuevo software ser libre y especificar que se baso en el mio.

Básicamente no se como hacer para aplicarle la licencia correcta y publicarlo en github.

Comment: Primero, [elige una licencia](https://choosealicense.com/). Luego, aprende a usar [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/).

Answer (score 1):

En este enlace oficial de GNU te explica muy bien como debes de licenciar tu proyecto o código con licencia libre:
[Cómo usar las licencias de GNU para su propio software](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.es.html)